# How to authenticate a METHOD GET request using node / express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

**Problem**

I have an api created that when I get a request it returns an array of data. The API url has to be used by an external development team.

What I want to achieve is that only they are the ones who can access the endpoint `/api/verily`

There will be a way that the team with api key can access the endpoint? And if possible, how could it be implemented?

I appreciate your help!

```js
app.get('/api/verily', (req, res) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
        .connect()
        .then((pool) => {
            return pool
                .request()
                .query(
                    "QUERY REMOVED... DESMOSTRATION ONLY"
                );
        })
        .then((result) => {
            Object.keys(result.recordset[0]).forEach(function (item) {
                const ft = JSON.parse(result.recordset[0][item]);
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.status(200).json(ft);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        });

    sql.close();
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at OAuth2? It's probably the most common architecture to implement authentication on apis.

Comment: Reading your comments @Chris Michael, it seems like you haven't clearly explained the workflow.  It's hard to answer your question without understanding what you want to do. EG-- how does the outside team get the API key? Is it fixed, or will you change it?

Comment: No, it is not implemented. That's the idea.

The idea would be how I can implement so that the dev passes a param with the value of the api key to the endpoint '/ api / verily'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one endpoint to protect, then [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) is probably the way to go.  If all you really care about is protecting a single endpoint with a fixed API key, and your consumers will pass in that key as a query parameter (say, `key`), you could:

```
const MY_API_KEY = "some-secret-value";

app.get('/api/verily', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.key !== MY_API_KEY) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  } else {
    // HANDLE APPROVED REQUEST HERE
  }
});
```

The request would go to `/api/verily?key=some-secret-value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by implementing middleware.
You can define a middleware function that will verify whether API sent via header or request params is genuine or not and if all is ok, you can return add true to you req.body.isAuthentic, once middleware returns using next() to the calling route, you can check whether it has returned true or false in the req.body.isAuthentic and proceed!

Sample Example:

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
app.get('/', middlware, function(req, res, next) {
if (req.body.isAuthentic) {
res.send('Hello World!');  }
});  
function middlware(req, res, next) {  
// check whether api is authentic
// if authentic then add req.body.isAuthentic = true;  
next();  
};
var server = app.listen(8000, function () {  
var host = server.address().address  
var port = server.address().port  
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)  
})
```

Comment: some example that and can follow?

Comment: See the updated answer, I have added the sample example.

Comment: The problem is that I will not be managing users, the idea would be that when the external development team of the other company uses the API URL, they are the only ones who can use the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a middleware as -

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
  // Extract token from the request header.
  const token = req.header("auth-token")

  // Check if token exists
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Access Denied." })

  try {
    const verified = verifyTheToken(inputToken, Actual Token)
    req.user = verified
    next()
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid Token." })
  }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Now, you can add this middleware called `verifyToken` (let's say) to your get request like so -

```
const verify = require("import/above/middleware/verifyToken.js")

app.get('/api/verily', auth, (req, res) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
        .connect()
        .then((pool) => {
            return pool
                .request()
                .query(
                    "QUERY REMOVED... DESMOSTRATION ONLY"
                );
        })
        .then((result) => {
            Object.keys(result.recordset[0]).forEach(function (item) {
                const ft = JSON.parse(result.recordset[0][item]);
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.status(200).json(ft);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        });

    sql.close();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution but it is not what I am really looking for, because in that case you should see an authenticated user.

But I am not looking for an auth user solution.

What I want to do is that when the development team requests the endpoint they are the only ones with access.

For this I was thinking of an implementation when the development team made a request to the API, asked to enter an api key before the request.

Comment: Please see my comment on your OP.  What do you mean when you say "when the development team made a request to the API, asked to enter an api key before the request"?  This seems like an important detail that should be explained in the question itself.